# Convert Value from name:value into Array when JSON string is Stringifyed

Tags: json, lightningjs

I have JSON to which i have done `JSON.stringify()` to pass the JSON into apex. Now i have one key:value such that value should be passed as array but since i am doing `JSON.stringify()`it is converting that array as string. So what can be done to get that "name":"value" from converted JSON string and then send the value as Array.

**Format i am excepting.**

//Removed some values so that code should not look big.

```
{
  "receivableaccount": "122",
  "taxItem": "230",
  "shippingitem": "12073",
  **"customer_currency":[2,3,4,5,6,8],
   **//(This is what i want [2,3,4,5,6,8] should be passed as array instead of string)**
  "addressbook": [
    {
      "addr1": "50 Corriveau Ave.",
      "zip": "T8N 3T5",
      "city": "St. Albert,",
      "country": "CA",
      "state": "Alberta"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code in JS-**

```
finalArr['recordtype'] = recordType;
finalArr['subsidiary'] = subsidary;
finalArr['custentity_customer_type'] = entityCusType;
finalArr['receivableaccount'] = receivableAcc; 
finalArr['taxItem'] = taxItem;
finalArr['shippingitem'] = shippingitem;
finalArr['customer_currency'] = customerCurrency;
finalArr['addressbook'] = addrFieldAttr;
jsonBody = JSON.stringify(finalArr);                    
component.set("v.jsonStr",jsonBody);
console.log('jsonBody of new customer '+jsonBody);
```

This jsonBody i am directly sending to Apex.

**JSON body i am getting through above code.**

```
{
  "companyname": "Uk test account",
  "custentity_salesforce_id": "153602",
  "subsidiary": "1",
  "terms": "Net 15",
  "recordtype": "customer",
  "custentity_customer_type": "2",
  "receivableaccount": "122",
  "taxItem": "230",
  "shippingitem": "12073",
  "customer_currency": "[2,3,4,5,6,8]",
  "addressbook": [
    {
      "addr1": "32 Princes Street",
      "zip": "EX19 2HD",
      "city": "Roborough",
      "country": "GB",
      "state": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did you create the JS variable `customerCurrency`? Without that, we have no idea why it would come in incorrectly. Also, You don't necessarily need to use JSON.stringify+JSON.deserialize, that's usually wasteful programming.

Comment: i am passing customerCurrency value form custom label. And since i am sending the request using HTTP i need to stringify them.Like below-
 Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            
            request.setEndPoint('callout:Netsuite_Salesforce_Integration'); //external URL
            request.setBody(jsonBody);
            request.setMethod('POST');

Comment: that label is having value as [2,3,4,5,6,8].

Comment: You'd want to `JSON.parse` the label, then, as in `JSON.parse(customerCurrency)`.

Comment: ok so how do i again store it in jsonBody which is a string.

Comment: `finalArr['customer_currency'] = JSON.parse(customerCurrency);` -- Sorry, had to edit this comment.

Comment: yes yes got it thank you very much. @sfdcfox.

Comment: Please can you put this in answer i will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize the label so that it becomes an object. It will then be serialized correctly later.

```
finalArr['customer_currency'] = JSON.parse(customerCurrency);
```

Comment: But since i am again doing JSON,stringify() to entire finalArr won't it convert again customer_currency value into string again,thinking that only i didn't go for parse.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Parsing makes it in to a real object, so when you stringify it later, it will be a JSON array with number values. Again, you don't necessarily need to stringify, it depends on how you wrote the Apex method.